# Why does a finitely oscillating sequence always has at least $2$ limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**Why** is it not possible to find a finite oscillating sequence which has only $1$ limit point or no limit point at all?

Why must it always have at least $2$?

I'm just not able to picture it.

Thanks

**EDIT** : I think I should've started out by saying how do you even picture a finite oscillating sequence? What is an intuitive way to imagine a finite oscillating sequence?

Comment: You should define your terms. It's hard for us to be sure what *you* mean by a "finite oscillating sequence". For example, does this sequence satisfy your definition of a finite oscillating sequence?? $$x_n = (-1)^n \cdot \frac{1}{n}$$

Comment: @LeeMosher but isn't the example you gave, an example of convergent sequence? My book literally says, a bounded sequence which is not convergent, is called a finitely oscillating sequence.

Comment: That's what I asked for, a definition. That definition should be part of your question. Which means that your question is *really*: Why does a bounded nonconvergent sequence always have at least 2 limit points?

Comment: @LeeMosher I thought finite oscillating sequence is one of the standard sequences. Because its almost mentioned in every real analysis book

Comment: One might find the term "oscillating" in every real analysis book, but using it in that precise fashion is rather nonstandard.

Comment: *its almost mentioned in every real analysis book* --- A google search indicates otherwise, and as someone who has a large collection of real analysis texts (I just checked, nearly 100 if advanced calculus texts are not included, and well over 100 if advanced calculus texts are included) who doesn't recognize "finite oscillating sequence", I disagree. The problem with this phrase (and thus why it's probably not used much) is that it is not clear whether "finite" refers to the sequence values (when extended real numbers are involved) or the magnitude of the oscillation (i.e. limsup - liminf).

Comment: I just noticed that your subject line uses "finitely oscillating sequence", which does seem to suggest $\limsup - \liminf < \infty.$ But "finite oscillating sequence" seems a bit ambiguous to me. If I had to guess, I would guess it means "finite-oscillating sequence" rather than "finite oscillating-sequence", but for the kind of question you're asking, you should make exactly precise what the definition you want to use. Indeed, for most people I think the answer would be immedate, as @Henry has given. Since it's not immediate to you, we need more background information about what you know.

Comment: If the sequence is bounded and has only one limit point then it converges to that limit point and thus does not oscillate finitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can always say that there always exist at least one limit point of a bounded sequence (why??)[ If It's infinite then we can apply Bolzano weierstrass theorem, otherwise it must be finite and must have a limit point].

Let $(a_n)$ be a finite oscillating sequence. Suppose there exists a limit point say $\alpha$ and since $(a_n)$ is not convergent implies there exists a subsequence which doesn't converge to $\alpha$ and the subsequence thus obtained is also a bounded subsequence, again by Bolzano Weierstrass theorem we get a new limit point.

Hence $(a_n)$ has at least 2 limit points

Answer (score 6):

If the sequence is bounded both above and below then it has [a limit inferior and a limit superior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior)

Each of these are limit points

If they were equal then that would be the single limit of the sequence, but then presumably it would not be called a *finite oscillating sequence*

Comment: If I have finite oscillating sequence $(a_n) = \left(2, 2.2, 2.22, 2.222, 2.2222, 2.22222, ... \right)$ then what are the $2$ limit points?

Comment: @William Why do you call that oscillating? A better example might be $1,2.3,2.21,2.223,2.2221,\ldots, \frac{20}{9} -(-10)^{-n}$ but for the question to make sense, it would not count as it converges

Comment: @William, The example you gave in your comment to this answer it not oscillating. It converges to 20/9.